# The right way to declare choices for django-form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I wonder what's the best way to set choices for `forms.ChoiceField` in Django.
I need a form which first will get the set of choices using SQL query (done with that) and then display it to the user. The problem with my solution is that I have the query in `forms.py` and it only updates once when I run the server. Any ideas how to make it update every time the form itself renders for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

`ModelChoiceField` is perfect for that. It takes `queryset` as required argument and the choices change every time the form is rendered.